# How do I make ggplot2 trendlines, one dashed and another a solid line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-visualization

I'd like each trendline on this graph to have a different shape. For example, the "boys" trendline would be dashed, and the "girls" trendline would be a solid line. I am using the `ggplot2` library in R. Here is my code.

```
dr <- ggplot(Tempdata, 
            aes(x = Tempdata$EffortfulControl,
                y = Tempdata$sqrt_Percent.5, 
                color = Tempdata$Sex1M, 
                shape = Tempdata$Sex1M)) + 
geom_point(aes(shape = Tempdata$Sex1M, 
               color = Tempdata$Sex1M), 
           show.legend = FALSE) + 
scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17))+ 
geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE) + 
labs(x = "xaxis label",
     y = "yaxis label", 
     fill = "") +
xlim(3,7) +
ylim(0,10)

dr +  
scale_colour_grey(start = 0.0, 
                  end = .7 , 
                  guide_legend(title = "")) + 
theme_classic()
```

[image]

Updated code after @nebroth 's suggestions

```
dr <- ggplot(Tempdata, 
       aes(x=Tempdata$EffortfulControl, 
           y=Tempdata$sqrt_Percent.5, 
           color=Tempdata$Sex1M, 
           shape=Tempdata$Sex1M, 
           linetype=Tempdata$Sex1M)) + geom_point(aes(shape=Tempdata$Sex1M, 
               color=Tempdata$Sex1M), 
           show.legend = FALSE) + 
scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17))+ geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE) + 
labs(x="xaxislabel", 
     y = "yaxis label", fill= "") + 
xlim(3,7) + 
ylim(0,10)

dr +  
scale_colour_grey(start = 0.0, 
                  end = 0.4, 
                  guide_legend(title = "")) + 
theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the answer to your question:
You can use the `linetype` parameter in `ggplot` with the grouping specified:
`ggplot(data, aes(x=x, y=y, color = z, linetype = z)`
If alternative data is specified in `aes` of `geom_smooth`, it can also be specified within `aes`.

A few more tips: In general you don't need to specify your object again within aes, you can just give the colname (e.g. `ggplot(Tempdata, aes(x=EffortfulControl, y=sqrt_Percent.5, color=Sex1M, shape=Sex1M))` ) and putting linebreaks between the different layers of your plot helps with readability.

Comment: Thank you!            
I tried adding in your suggested aes code within geom_smooth, and the graph looks largely the same:     

```
dr <- ggplot(Tempdata, aes(x=Tempdata$EffortfulControl, y=Tempdata$sqrt_Percent.5, color=Tempdata$Sex1M, shape=Tempdata$Sex1M)) + geom_point(aes(shape=Tempdata$Sex1M, color=Tempdata$Sex1M), show.legend = FALSE) + scale_shape_manual(values=c(16,17))+ geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE, aes(linetype= "dashed")) + labs(x="xaxislabel", y = "yaxis label", fill= "") + xlim(3,7) + ylim(0,10)
```
https://imgur.com/mXoNQYr

@nebroth

Comment: Okay, that only works if you specified data in `aes`. But you can specify `linetype = "dashed"` outside of `aes`, that should do the trick.
I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @cellophane_flowers
Please post only relevant code in your answers, it's very hard to find the relevant part of your code, especially in your comment (or format it as suggested in my answer).

Comment: Thank you for your patience and continued support! I'm new to stack overflow. With your suggested edits, my graph now has both lines as dashed. How could I make one solid and one dashed?

geom_smooth(method=lm,se=FALSE,fullrange=TRUE, linetype= "dashed") 

https://imgur.com/o6sq7zN

Comment: @cellophane_flowers
Ok, I see the problem. In that case add `linetype = Sex1M` to the `aes` of your ggplot:
`ggplot(Tempdata, aes(x=EffortfulControl, y=sqrt_Percent.5, color=Sex1M, shape=Sex1M, linetype = Sex1M))`
And remove the `linetype` from `geom_smooth`

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! I now have an extra legend on the side, but the lines look correct! 

https://imgur.com/KXmdiO8

Comment: Can you post your code again? I suspect you now used different way of specifying your groups: You have to either never use the object name or always use it. Otherwise you end up with mulitple legends. And if everything works please mark the answer as correct :)

Comment: I updated the code in the original post! I just need to get rid of the extra legend now.

Comment: You don't need to specify the `aes` in `geom_point`. With my data I only get one legend, maybe that changes it. Can you provide sample data so I can try with your data instead of using mine?

Comment: I tried your code with some dummy dataframe and the `guide_legend(title = ""))` in the end seems to trigger the additional legend. Try removing that and you should only have one legend left. And Remove the `Tempdata$` from your code, it's just dead weight.

Comment: Removing the `guide_legend(title = ""))` from my code fixed it. Thank you for the additional comments on my code. Much of this was pieced together from many googles. I appreciate your time!